Why is the overall phase of a wave traveling backward notated as $-kx - \omega t$ instead of $kx + \omega t$?
in textbook i read the equation for the wave equation that travel forward in the $+x$ direction is
$$ 
y(x,t) = Ae^{i(kx -ωt)} 
$$
and for wave equation that travel backward in the $-x$ direction is
$$ 
y(x,t) = Ae^{i(-kx -ωt)} 
$$
and it seem a bit counterintuitive for me. After all, the $kx - ωt$ term comes from the function translation in the $+x$ direction, $f(x, t) = f(x - vt, t=0)$, and we define $kv = ω$ as in $k(x - vt)$. Then, if the wave is described by a function that translates in the $-x$ direction, $f(x, t) = f(x - (-v)t, t=0)$, shouldn't the wave moving backward in the $-x$ direction be $Ae^{i(kx + ωt)}$ instead?
I've read some explanations that mention the initial delay phase $φ$ of $Ae^{i(kx - ωt + φ)}$, but I'm still not quite clear on this. In my understanding, we can adjust for any initial phase by introducing the term $e^{iφ}$ and combining it with the amplitude $A$ anyway, as seen in the equation derived from the boundary condition of the wave. So why is the overall phase of a wave moving backward notated as $-kx - ωt$ instead of $kx + ωt$?


$-kx-\omega t=-(kx+\omega t)$; in either case, the wave is going in the $-x$ direction. Clearly equivalent ways to describe such waves. It does not matter which one you choose.

Let us first consider the wave
$$y(x,t) = Ae^{i(kx - \omega t)}$$
Looking at the phase in the exponent we see,
the places of constant phase are given by
$$kx - \omega t = \text{const}.$$
Differentiating this we get
$$k\ dx - \omega\ dt = 0$$
or
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{\omega}{k}$$
So the places of constant phase move
with velocity $\frac{\omega}{k}$, i.e. to the right.

Now let us repeat this for the other wave
$$y(x,t) = Ae^{i(-kx - \omega t)}$$
Here the places of constant phase are given by
$$-kx - \omega t = \text{const}.$$
Differentiating this we get
$$-k\ dx - \omega\ dt = 0$$
or
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{\omega}{k}$$
So the places of constant phase move
with velocity $-\frac{\omega}{k}$, i.e. to  the left.
And by the way: For $e^{i(kx+\omega t)}$ you would get
the same velocity $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{\omega}{k}$, i.e. to the left.

Quite interesting explanation, but I'm not able to follow with respect to what are you differentiating expression $-kx - \omega t = \text{const}.$ ?

@AgniusVasiliauskas Just rewrite it as: $x = \mathrm{const} -\omega t/k$ and differentiate with respect to $t$.

@agaminon Ok. I see now, thanks. Just tiny correction,- solving for x we get $x=-\frac {\text{const}}{k}-\frac {\omega t}{k}$. Differentiating this we still arrive at the same answer $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{\omega}{k}$, assuming wavenumber $k$ is constant. If not,- we are in trouble.

Notice that $-(kx+\omega t)=-kx-\omega t$. The problem here is that the textbook is using two different conventions to describe the same thing. In complex representation, waves can be expressed in two equivalent ways:
$$e^{-i(kx-\omega t)} \ \mathrm{or} \ e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$$
The two representations are solutions to the wave equation and are therefore valid. The first one is a phasor that rotates clockwise as the phase grow (it starts at $0$, then goes into negative angles, the way a clock's hands would move) and the second one represents a phasor rotating counter clockwise. Your textbook is using the second convention for the forward-traveling wave and the first convention for the backward-traveling wave. Normally, one would use only one of these conventions to avoid this kind of confusion.

So from notation of overall phase of traveling wave in both notation. when solving the boundary conditions I should get the same ratio of transmission right???
